# textbox asp net validator for numerical, accept decimal

Tags: asp.net, regex, textbox, numeric

i want to make textbox that contain numerical value, but it have to accept decimal number

valid:

- 1
- 1.2
- 1.23
- 1.234
- 0.0011 etc

but it will give error message if

- 1,234
- 1,23abc
- 1.3454.21

this is my code so far

```
<asp:TextBox Font-Bold="true" ID="TextBoxTaxValue" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxString"
                            Width="80px"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="%"></asp:Label>
                        <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server"
                            TargetControlID="TextBoxTaxValue" FilterType="Custom, Numbers" ValidChars="." />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="One '.' only!"
                            ControlToValidate="TextBoxTaxValue" ValidationExpression="^(-)?\d+(\.\d\d)?$" />
```

please help me

Comment: And what is not working? Just replace the `\d\d` by `\d+` as you did for the integer part.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` &
ValidationExpression like below
`(^[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$)|(^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$)|(^[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$)`